# Preventing Thread.CurrentPrincipal from propagating across application domains

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Does anyone if it's possible to stop the current thread's IPrincipal from propagating over an application domain boundary? I have no control over the IPrincipal that's assigned to the thread, but I do have control over creating the application domains.

(The reason I want to do this is to prevent a serialization error from occuring if the principal object type's assembly is unavailable in the other domain.)

Edit: `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow` looks promising, but it doesn't appear to achieve the goal. The following prints "MyIdentity":

```
static void Main ()
{
    ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow ();
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal (new GenericIdentity ("MyIdentity"), "Role".Split ());
    AppDomain.CreateDomain ("New domain").DoCallBack (Isolated);
}

static void Isolated ()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Current principal: " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);  // MyIdentity
}
```

Comment: In case anyone else is trying to solve an obscure problem like this: I was able to get what I needed by spinning up a thread and setting ```Thread.CurrentPrincipal``` within the thread to the desired principal. Then I could call ```AppDomain.DoCallBack``` in that thread for the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't run an asynchronous method, the target function is executed in the secondary appdomain by the same thread.  So the principal doesn't change.  This works:

```
        var flow = ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("MyIdentity"), "Role".Split());
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) => {
            AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain").DoCallBack(Isolated);
        });
        flow.Undo();
```

Or if you just want to run the same thread with a specific context then you can use ExecutionContext.Run():

```
        var copy = ExecutionContext.Capture();
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("MyIdentity"), "Role".Split());
        ExecutionContext.Run(copy, new ContextCallback((x) => {
            AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain").DoCallBack(Isolated);
        }), null);
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do what you want:

[System.Threading.ExecutionContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx)

Specifically, take a look at the SuppressFlow method.

Chris